# Javascript MutationObserver Error

Tags: javascript, mutation-observers

The following script works, but chrome says that there is an error..
What should I do to solve this error?

```
function Do(){alert("test");}

new MutationObserver(Do).observe(document.body,{childList:true,subtree:true}); //works, but there's error.
```

The error message in chrome console is this;

> Uncaught NotFoundError: An attempt was made to reference a Node in a
>   context where it does not exist. (anonymous function)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Node body has not been created when chrome executes the code. So you can change your code like this:

```
    window.onload=function(){
      function Do(){alert("test");};
      new MutationObserver(Do).observe(document.body,{childList:true,subtree:true});
    };
```

or do with jQuery:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    //your code
    });
```

Comment: Thank you. Error disappeared.